# PHP MYSQL CONCAT with string containing comma in the start

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

Its a strange problem that I am having. I am trying to update a value in the database table with a new one by concatenating old and new values with a comma in between. So basically my value now is:
 Hello and I am updating it to World and I want the new value to be Hello,world but I am unable to do this. Both the CONCAT and CONCAT_WS functions through an error that you have invalid syntax.

Table name is fields. The column I wish to update is values and the new value to be concatenated is $newval. Here is my query.

```
$sql="update fields set values=CONCAT_WS(',',values, '$newval') where name='fundType'";
```

I get this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'values=CONCAT_WS(',',values, 'Buyout') where name='fundType'' at line 1
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Ahmar A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`values` is a keyword of mysql. use backticks ``` `` ``` to mark it as a field name:

```
$sql="update fields set `values`=CONCAT_WS(',',`values`, '$newval') where name='fundType'";
```